# Unable to retrieve a property from oozie.action.conf.xml

Tags: java, hadoop, action, config, oozie

I am trying to access a property that is set through oozie java action configuration but I am not getting the value I was looking for, wondering if I can get any help on this?

My workflow

```
...........
<action name="ref-record-load">
 <java>
    <configuration>
    <property>
      <name>oozie.launcher.mapred.child.java.opts</name>
      <value>-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>load.type</name>
      <value>full</value>
    </property>
  </configuration>
.............
```

and I am trying to access this property from my code in the following way

```
        oozieConfigFile = System.getProperty("oozie.action.conf.xml");
        final FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(oozieConfigFile);
        final Properties oozieConfigProperties = new Properties();
        oozieConfigProperties.loadFromXML(inputStream);
        loadType = oozieConfigProperties.getProperty("load.type");
```

But I don't see any value populated in loadType. Is there something wrong in the way I am trying to access the property?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xml file is there. However it couldn't be loaded by loadFromXML(). Try use hadoop configuraion class:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
... 
Configuration conf = new Configuration(false);
conf.addResource(new Path(System.getProperty("oozie.action.conf.xml")));
String loadType = conf.get("load.type")
...
```

It should work.

Comment: Will try this. Thank you paul. However, out of curiosity may I know the reason why loadFromXML() won't work?. Isn't the "oozie.action.conf.xml" representation of properties in xml file ?

Comment: a captured xml snippet and exception may help here. With file like this:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><configuration>
<property><name>dfs.journalnode.rpc-address</name><value>0.0.0.0:8485</value><source>hdfs-default.xml</source></property> </configuration>, Got an Exception in thread "main" java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 70; Document root element "configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
 at java.util.XMLUtils.load(XMLUtils.java:76)
 at java.util.Properties.loadFromXML(Properties.java:868)